# Trying to take the number from the first column of each row, and insert it as the id of the <tr> element

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code. I am trying to take the value of the innerHTML for each row of a column in my table, and then add this to a `<tr>` element as `<tr id="1"> <tr id="47">`, etc

```
window.onload = function inventorytable() {
var tableRows = document.getElementById("inventorytable").rows;
var idxarray = "";

for(var i = 1, l = tableRows.length; i < l; i++) {
    var tds = tableRows[i].cells;
    tds[7].innerHTML += " Ghz"
    tds[8].innerHTML += " GB"
    tds[10].innerHTML += " Mhz"
    idxarray = idxarray += tds[0].innerHTML  //THIS IS WHERE I AM NOT SURE WHAT TO DO
}}
```

How do I take the information contained in tds[0].innerHTML for each row, and put it as that row's id?

Comment: DOM IDs must start with a letter http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: Ok, then this question is the exact same, just have it append row to the front of the character :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused. Are you trying to take the inner-html of column 0 of each row and make that the id (prepended with row-) of the parent tr? If so would this do the trick?...

```
window.onload = function inventorytable() {
    var tableRows = document.getElementById("inventorytable").rows;

    for(var i = 1, l = tableRows.length; i < l; i++) {
        var tds = tableRows[i].cells;
        tds[7].innerHTML += " Ghz"
        tds[8].innerHTML += " GB"
        tds[10].innerHTML += " Mhz"
        tableRows[i].id = 'row-' + tds[0]; 
    }
}
```